# I have data as mentioned below, i need to replace data in string fields to any other data by using UNIX

Tags: unix

I have  data as mentioned below, i need to replace data in string fields to any other data by using UNIX.

Actual data:  123,abcd,456,efgh,789

Required data:  123,acbd,456,rfad,789

Comment: This is a trivial question with thousands of easily available answers. Start by Googling e.g. `unix replace strings`

Answer (score 0):

Use sed, awk, or perl. There should be a lot of similar questions already. For starters, best use sed:

```
cat input_file | sed 's/,efgh,/,rfad,/g'
```

What you find and how you change it to is between the "/".

This is a bit longer, but safer, and more generic:

```
cat input_file | awk -F, -vOFS=, '{ sub(efgh,rfad,$3); print }'
```

In both commands you're speaking the language of the tool you are invoking in the quotes. "$3" stands for 3-rd field in awk, "-F" defines the field separator, "-vOFS=" defines the output field separator.